# The argument type 'BorderRadius?' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'BorderRadius' flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, border-radius

I am having an **InputDecoration** which has the border property, If a certain condition is true i apply **OutlineInputBorder** or else i set it to `null` which is working correctly. I also want to apply `borderRadius` if a certain condition is true but i am getting the error `The argument type 'BorderRadius?' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'BorderRadius'` if i apply the `borderRadius` without the if statement its just working correctly what might be the issue. Below is my code

```
decoration: InputDecoration(
                                        labelText:
                                            enableDropDownFormFieldLabelText
                                                ? "Select Car"
                                                : null,
                                        border:
                                            enableCustomizableDropDownFormFieldOutlineInputBorder
                                                ? OutlineInputBorder(
                                                    borderRadius: enableCustomizableDropDownFormFieldOutlineInputBorderBorderRadius
                ? BorderRadius.circular(15): null)
                                                : null,
                                        contentPadding: const EdgeInsets.only(
                                            left: 10, right: 5))
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`BorderRadius` can not be `null`. Use `BorderRadius.circular(0)` istead.

```
decoration: InputDecoration(
                                    labelText:
                                        enableDropDownFormFieldLabelText
                                            ? "Select Car"
                                            : null,
                                    border:
                                        enableCustomizableDropDownFormFieldOutlineInputBorder
                                            ? OutlineInputBorder(
                                                borderRadius: enableCustomizableDropDownFormFieldOutlineInputBorderBorderRadius
            ? BorderRadius.circular(15): BorderRadius.circular(0))
                                            : null,
                                    contentPadding: const EdgeInsets.only(
                                        left: 10, right: 5))
```

Comment: In my flutter this error is not in any lib file.
when I run the application then this error occurs.